Science-fiction movie about the moon and how its' orbit had changed!
I am looking for a sci-fi movie about the moon. I recall the moon's orbit changing, so that it becomes more oval, not rounded. Scientists do equations to determine when the moon will hit the earth. The moon might have been hit by a meteor, but I am not sure. Finally someone realizes that a decimal in one of the calculations was out by one place, and the earth is safe.
The movie is in color, roughly within the last 25 years and I believe it to be American. It is not "Impact" or "Deep Impact" or a TV series.
Can anyone identify this movie?

Sounds like a real cop-out ending. "Oh, we misplaced a decimal point..sorry"...not much action there.

Syfy C movie of the week

It sounds an awful lot like Earthstorm from 2006 with Stephen Baldwin.

A massive asteroid impact on the moon begins causing storms on earth due to the sudden changes in ocean tides. But when further examination is conducted it's discovered that the moon's structure is now entirely unstable -- threatening all life on earth. With time running out, a team of scientists turn to one man, demolitions expert John Redding, in effort to find a solution and secure the moon.

There are some problems with the math, but I think they make matters worse and the team realizes they'd have to penetrate the moon's core to nuke it (and I know, the plot is so much like Armageddon, it might as well by an Asylum production). Here's the trailer:




Some slight variance in the details, but could this be Melancholia?
The differences being that it's a planet, not a moon; and the realization that the orbit was miscalculated results in the planet colliding with Earth, as opposed to missing?

On the night of her wedding to Michael (Alexander Skarsgård), Justine
  (Kirsten Dunst) struggles with premonitions of a blue planet called
  Melancholia, on a collision course with the Earth. Ironically, while
  the ensuing oblivion brings on a condition of depressive, Melancholia,
  Justine's sister, Claire (Charlotte Gainsbourg), struggles to maintain
  composure and calm around her as impending disaster unsettles
  everyone. The extravagant wedding, paid for by Justine's
  brother-in-law, is shattered as the husband and guests depart and the
  sisters are left to deal with the impending cataclysm alone.

The film is actually about depression, but uses the planet sub-plot as a cipher for depression. 
